# python create canvas objects with variables from list

Tags: python, tkinter

So I have a list in Python like this:

`stabe = ["stab1","stab2","stab3","stab4","stab5","stab6"]`

and I want to create Tkinter Canvas rectangles named like the elements of the list, I tried this so far but it doesn't work:

`for i in range(n):
        stabe[i] = canvas.create_rectangle(50+co, 750-coy, 200-co ,740-coy, 
        fill='gray', outline='gray')`

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work? What is it doing that is different from what you expect?

Comment: A not recommended way is `globals()[stabe[i]] = canvas.create_rectangle(...)`.  How about using dict, like `rectangles[stabe[i]] = canvas.create_rectangle(...)`.